# Meteor resources don't include .mp4 for bigvideo.js

Tags: javascript, video, meteor

I'm building a meteor app and I hope to use bigvideo.js. However, the apps resources doesn't include public/vid/video.mp4. I moved the video to public/img/picture.jpg and the .jpg works but the .mp4, once again is not there.

---

app packages:


insecure

standard-app-packages

bootstrap

iron-router

spin

accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

accounts-password

iron-router-progress

jquery-ui

modernizr-meteor

jquery

---

I'm not sure what else will be helpful. Thanks ahead of time for anyones help.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "not there"? What do you get when you open the URL `yourserver:yourport/vid/video.mp4`? a 404?

Comment: For Meteor, you can store anything in public and it will be served via url automatically.
If you have public/vid/video.mp4 for instance, it will be served under /vid/video.mp4

However since it looks like since you're using the BigVideo.js script you need to load the video with an absolute path. This is more about where the script is stored and how to get it to find the correct video path.

Comment: @ChristianFritz - yourserver:yourport/vid/video.mp4 does bring me back the video. However, use the browsers inspector (chrome) and look at the pages resource vid/video.mp4 isn't there but pic/picture.jpg is, Which are both in public.

Comment: @Pent - Thanks that sounds like that could be the issue. I was unsure where to put bigvideo.js so I put it in client/helpers. How would I go about finding the absolute path? Also would you have any recommendations for placing bigvideo.js?

Thanks guys!

Comment: we'll need to see your bigvideo code to help you further. You now know the absolute path for your video (you opened it yourself). So the question is how to correctly point bigvideo to it.